# Power BI - Creating a Clustered Column Chart with Multiple (X-Axis) Values

Tags: powerbi

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
A    Bucket1 StatusX
B    Bucket2 StatusY
C    Bucket3 StatusX
D    Bucket1 StatusY
E    Bucket2 StatusX
F    Bucket2 StatusX
G    Bucket1 StatusY
H    Bucket2 StatusX
I    Bucket2 StatusX
J    Bucket2 StatusZ
```

I would like to create a graph that has the following axis:

```
Y-Axis : Count
X-Axis : Bucket by Status (Grouped by Bucket)
```

Using the datasource above I would end up with something along the lines of

```
|              _
|             |X|
|      _      |X|
|  _  |Y|     |X|  _     _
| |X| |Y|     |X| |Y|   |X| _  
-------------------------------------------------
  Bucket1   Bucket2    Bucket3
```

Note: You may have noticed that **data item J** has a **StatusZ**.  This is deliberate as my actual datasource has some status that I don't want to include in this graph.

So far I have the following visualization settings

- Chart Type : Clustered Column Chart
- Axis : Bucket Value : Count of Status & Count of Status  **(I think this is where the problem)**

In Visual Level Filters I have:

- Bucket(All)
- Count of Status
- Status is Basic Filtering to only include StatusX and StatusY

So, where have I gone wrong?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pull "Bucket" to Axis, pull "Status" to Legend, and pull "Status" again to Value, where it will be counted.

Each status is now a series and plotted by its count per bucket. Set the filter to include only X and Y status.

[image]

Comment: Thankyou! So simple, but I have been banging my head against this for a few hours #powerbinewbie

Comment: Yeah, the "legend equals series" concept may take some time to sink in.